# Control the Raspberry PI on Serial Port communication

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, uart

I am trying to control raspberry pi on serial port connection(UART), I can send data from raspberry (with some app for serial communication) with

`echo xyz > /dev/ttyAMA0;` this works, also I can receive data with

`cat /dev/ttyAMA0;`  also works,

Now for example I want to send "ls" and raspberry pi should see that data as a command line and return the result , My question is, how can I do such a communication ?

(The end goal of this project is to send a command to raspberry pi to start  some c++ program and it should return the program result.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some kind of bridge between serial port and shell.

Have a look at this implementation - it will hopefully answer your question: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/Serial_Linux#Serial_I.2FO_on_the_Shell_Command_Line